# Booking System in Java

Tags: java, oop

Its a cinema booking system. My system has 2 different types of Room (common room and 3D room) and a class of reservations (with name, age and date).

```
public class Room {

    int number;
    int capacity;
    List<Reservations> reservation = new ArrayList();

// constructor

    public Room(int number, int capacity, List<Reservations> reservation) {
        this.number = number;
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.reservation = reservation;
    }
}
```

```
public class Reservations {

    String name;
    int age;
    Date date;
    
    public Reservations(String name, int age, Date date) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

```
public class CommonRoom extends Room{

    public CommonRoom(int number, int capacity, List<Reservations> reservation) {
        super(number, capacity, reservation);
}

public class 3DRoom extends Room{

    public 3DRoom(int number, int capacity, List<Reservations> reservation) {
        super(number, capacity, reservation);
}
```

How can I make a reservation for Common Rooms and 3D Rooms? Because the list only store type Reservations, and I need to store CommonRooms and 3DRooms.

Comment: Well, you need some `class MovieTheater { List<Room> rooms; }`...

Comment: We would need to know more about your application. Without knowing more, might I suggest two instances of `List <Reservations>`, one for Common Rooms and the other for 3D rooms?  If not that, what about adding `RoomType` variable to `Reservations` class?

Comment: Your system has three types of rooms, not just two. What is a `CommonRoom`? The toilet? ;) Seriously: how differs `CommonRoom` from `Room` ?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: Again, do not deface your question. I will ask the moderators to lock this question.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your question is too broad for Stack Overflow. But your code currently looks confused in terms of design so I'll offer some thoughts.

Firstly, why would the `Room` (the theatre where the films are screened) be responsible for handling its own reservations? Wouldn't it be better to have a `BoxOffice` class which handles the reservations for the whole cinema?

Secondly, what does a `Room` (theatre) actually need to do? If we move the handling of tickets to a `BoxOffice`, then keeping track of reservations would also be handled there. Each `Room` would just need to be able to return the name of the room, the capacity of the room, the seat map for the room (if you want to allow customers to pre-book a specific seat) and any special features (such as support for 3D movies, fancy surround sound, etc).

Thirdly, is there any real difference between a standard theatre and a 3D theatre in terms of your booking software? Probably not, and in fact a `BoxOffice` would need to be able to keep track of reservations, remaining capacity, and specific seat numbers still available, regardless of which type of theatre is being booked. (Don't forget that each theatre will show several different movie showings each day, so you'd need a `MovieScreening` type too which the `BoxOffice` links to reservations.) So there's probably no good reason to use inheritance to define `Room` and then `CommonRoom` and `3DRoom` and it would be cleaner to simply have `Room` and use a `name` field and a `supportedFeatures` field to differentiate the different theatres in your cinema, allowing all of them to fit within the same `List<Room>` or `Map<MovieScreening, Room>` without worrying about the mess caused by subclasses.

If this is in fact just a homework exercise where your tutor is trying to get you to show off an example of using inheritance, then ignore all of this advice. But be aware that inheritance is more often a curse than a benefit, and there's usually a better way of structuring your type hierarchy.